# changing the text in a toolbar with pywinauto

Tags: toolbar, pywinauto

I have a file selection window from an windows application I'm trying to automate.

[image]

I can change the File name box at the bottom by using

```
app2.window(title_re='Select a batch file') \
            .File_name_Edit.set_text(selected_filename)
```

I have previously entered the full filepath and filename in to the lower box, however, it will no longer accept slashes in the File name box after a windows update. Hence the problem.

So the problem is the top (directory/folder name) box.

Manually I can select the box, highlight it then overtype the directory.

I cannot find a way to do this using pywinauto.

Methods attempted are:

```
toolbar2 = app2.window(title_re='Select a batch file')  # \
#     .child_window(title_re='Address', auto_id='1001')
#     .child_window(title_re='Address', control_type="ToolBar", auto_id='1001')
file_path_address = toolbar2['Address band toolbarToolbar'].click_input()
file_path_address.set_text(directory_path)

# ToolbarWrapper(toolbar2).set_text(directory_path)
# ToolbarWrapper(toolbar2).click(button='All locationsSplitButton').set_text(directory_path)
# ToolbarWrapper(toolbar2)['Address:'].set_text(directory_path)
```

I'm using set_text as the automation must run behind a locked screen, type_keys does not work with a locked screen as type_keys is a keyboard method and Windows blocks keyboard entry when the screen is locked.

I have no access to the internals of the program being automated in order to change the original directory path and need to change it to read in from a different location.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See below code, It runs fine with Notepad++ on Win 10

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Connect(title=u'Open', class_name='#32770')
window = app.Dialog

toolbarwindow = window.Toolbar3
toolbarwindow.Click()
time.sleep(0.30)

static = window.Edit2
directory_path = "C:\Users\Desktop"

raw_directory_path = r'{}'.format(directory_path)
static.set_edit_text(text = raw_directory_path)
static.type_keys("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: As a follow on question.  I cannot 'fix' the text in the toolbar. Moving to any other field causes the directory path to revert to its original value and not remain as the result of the set_edit_text. So if the original is '''C:\user\fred''' and the value entered using set_edit_text is '''C:\user\john''' I want the toolbar to remain pointing at 'john' when I set the filename at the bottom of the window, trying to do so resets the toolbar.

Comment: @RoyJaques after set_edit_text(), press ENTER. Try this `static.type_keys("{ENTER}")` I have updated the code in answer above, it worked for me on Notepad++

Comment: I'm coming back to this later as something else has come to the top of the 'to do' list. However, I cannot use type_keys as it will not work when windows has a screen lock. This is a Microsoft 'feature' and is an issue when I'm trying to automate an interactive process which will be left to run overnight.

Answer (score 1):

you can use right click then edit the field

```
toolbar2['Address band toolbarToolbar'].click_input(button="right")
app2.PopupMenu.child_window(title="Edit address", control_type="MenuItem").click_input()
app2.child_window(title="Address", control_type="Edit").set_edit_text(directory_path)
```